# Is there any way in CSS to align an element to the end of the final linebox of a sibling?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to achieve the layout shown in this mockup?

[image: Three examples of some main text (large, black) aligned left, and then adjacent supplementary text (smaller, green) aligned right. The supplementary text is vertically aligned to the baseline of the final linebox of the adjacent main text. The first example's main text is short enough to only take up a single line and still fit the supplementary text on the same line. The second example's text takes up two lines with enough space for the supplementary text to also share the second line. In the third example, the main text is only one line but does not leave enough space for the supplementary text, which is therefore right-aligned in its own linebox below.]

The supplementary text is right-aligned and if there is space it shares the same linebox as the final line of the main text.

### Things I've tried

#### Floating the supplementary text.

Problems with this approach:

- It's a float, so has all the edge cases and bugs floats have, and the next element has to deal with clearing it, and margins act in unexpected ways.
- If the supplementary text is a different size, it's difficult to align it to the same baseline as the main text since `vertical-align` does not work on floating elements. It's possible to align them if all sizes are known, but in most cases this will require extra wrapper elements.
- To share the same line as the main text, the supplementary text has to come first (this is unacceptable for me) or the main text has to be floating rather than the supplementary. And the latter case only works when the main text and supplementary text all fit on a single line, otherwise the supplementary will be below the final linebox of the main text.

Here it is with the supplementary text floated right, in both orders:

```css
article {
  clear: both;
}

header p {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <header>
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing</h2>
    <p>Supplementary</p>
  </header>
</article>

<article>
  <header>
    <p>Supplementary</p>
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing</h2>
  </header>
</article>
```

#### Flexbox

This is better in one way: flex items can be aligned by baseline without extra wrappers and tricky styling. However:

- If flex wrap is not enabled the supplemental text will only ever align to the *first* baseline of the main text, and the horizontal area available to *all* lines of the main text is reduced by however much space the supplemental text takes up.
- If flex wrap is enabled and the main text wraps to a second line, or otherwise doesn't leave enough space for the supplemental text, the main text's flex element's width is the full width of the flexbox or close to it, and so the supplemental text will always be on a new flex line, even if there is visual space available for it in the main text's last linebox.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}

header p {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing</h2>
  <p>Supplementary</p>
</header>

<header style="flex-wrap: wrap">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing</h2>
  <p>Supplementary</p>
</header>
```

#### Absolute positioning

This is no good since if absolutely positioned, the supplemental text doesn't reserve any space and it may overlap with the main text.

Comment: to easy clear float, simply add `overflow:auto` to header this will make the element self-cleared and no need to bother about the next element clearing it

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely an interesting issue. Unfortunately, it does actually seem like a prime usecase for `inline` and `floated` elements, as much of a pain as they are. Of course it's a bit more difficult to see how they'll interact in a "real world" environment, but if you were to use the "`:after` as a table" clearfix, make the `h2` inline, float the `p`, **and** remove the line-height of it, it should rest at the bottom of the typographic x-height of the `h2`.

Here's a quick demo:

```css
article:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
header h2 {
  display: inline;
}
header p {
  float: right;
  line-height: 0;
}

/* Just for example layout */
body{width:100vw;overflow-x:hidden;min-height:100vh;display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center}div{max-width:50%}header p{position:relative}header p:after{content:"";position:absolute;width:calc(50vw - 40px);height:1px;background:red;top:6px;right:0}article{padding:20px;border:1px solid #ccc}
```

```html
<div>
  <article>
    <header>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <p>Supplementary</p>
    </header>
  </article>
  <article>
    <header>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipi…</h2>
      <p>Supplementary</p>
    </header>
  </article>
  <article>
    <header>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing Lorem ipsum.</h2>
      <p>Supplementary</p>
    </header>
  </article>
</div>
```

---

Interesting note, as @Temani Afif noted, you can replace the `article:after { content: ""; display: table; clear: both; }` with `header { overflow: auto; }` to make it self-clearing. A nice little trick to prevent littering your CSS with clear fixes

Comment: Oh, this shows that the `display: contents` used in nullqube's answer wasn't necessary; that's an improvement. Expanded example here: https://codepen.io/tremby/pen/mdrXQYO -- as you'll see I did a lot of acrobatics to make sure that line-height and size differences are handled in all cases...

Comment: The expanded example in my previous comment also handles multiple lines of supplementary (rather than setting line-height to 0 like in your example). This solves the issue almost fully, I think, it's just a shame the font sizes need to be known, that so much nasty `calc` is needed to get the baselines aligned, that there's a magic number involved, and that if the supplementary is alone on a line it takes the full line height of the main text.

Comment: Clearing etc is a widely-known issue btw and doesn't need to feature in the answer. Is it OK if I edit your answer to include my expanded example?

Comment: I need to point out as well that with your (much cleaner and simpler!) code the baselines only align by luck -- if the font size of the main or supplementary text are changed they will no longer align.

Answer (score 1):

```css
h2 {
    display: contents;
}

p {
    float: right;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

article {
    clear: both;
}

article:after {
    content: "";
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <header>
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing blah blahh blahhhh, and long looong looooooong text content</h2>
    <p>Supplementary</p>
  </header>
</article>
<br>
<article>
  <header>
    <p>Supplementary</p>
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing</h2>
  </header>
</article>
```

and then without `display: contents`
and the extra gap that came can solve by setting `line-height` on the *h2* (ex: `line-height:1em;`)

```css
h2 {
    display: inline;
    /*line-height: 1em;*/
}

p {
    float: right;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

article {
    clear: both;
}

article:after {
    content: "";
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <header>
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing blah blahh blahhhh, and long looong looooooong text content</h2>
    <p>Supplementary</p>
  </header>
</article>
<br>
<article>
  <header>
    <p>Supplementary</p>
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing</h2>
  </header>
</article>
```

Comment: Interesting. I took this and ran with it; see here: https://codepen.io/tremby/pen/NWRyEMv -- the main issue is that `display: contents` isn't supported everywhere, and in Chromium-based browsers there's a current bug where it's removed from the accessibility tree (link in the Codepen notes).

Comment: ohhh, you can get same result with `display:inline;` too @tremby